# SharePoint SPFile change extension on existing item possible?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, file-extension, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I am at my wits end on this one. I have a user interface that creates and edits documents stored in a SharePoint document library. The trick part is I need to allow the user to update the document no problem just use `SPFile.SaveBinary()` right?

This definitely updates the contents of the file but somehow the old file name and the old extension persist, this is a problem. Deleting and re-adding the list item is not a solution either because the id of the item is being referenced in the url.

My question is how can I update the extension and filename metadata of the SPFile item?

So far all of my attempts using the object library have failed, i've tried updating the fields below none have been successful. It seems like there has to be an easier way to do this.

```
SPFile file = item.File;
file.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.FileLeafRef] = resolvedFileName;
file.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.FileRef] = "/File/" + resolvedFileName;
file.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.BaseName] = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(resolvedFileName);
file.Item["Name"] = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(resolvedFileName);
file.SaveBinary(conduitFile);
file.Update();
```

**[EDIT]** - Here is my working solution.

```
SPFile file = item.File;
string resolvedFileName = item.ID.ToString() + "-" + conduitFileName;
item["Title"] = resolvedFileName;
file.SaveBinary(conduitFile);
file.MoveTo(item.ParentList.RootFolder.Url + "/" + resolvedFileName, true);
file.Item["Name"] = resolvedFileName;
file.Update();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the file is saved to the library, use the `MoveTo` method and pass the modified file name in the `newUrl` parameter.

[SPFile.MoveTo Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms468280.aspx)
[Quick & Easy: Rename Uploaded File Using SharePoint Object Model Via an Event Receiver](http://paulgalvin.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!1CC1EDB3DAA9B8AA!655.entry)

Answer (score 4):

Another way that is simpler than using the MoveTo is to use the **BaseName** property of the SPListItem.  You would set this by running

```
item["BaseName"] = resolvedFileName; //Whatever you want the new file name to be 
item.Update();
```

This is easier than MoveTo because you don't have to worry about the folder hierarchy and you don't have to worry about the file extension.

For some reason the property is not listed on the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem_properties.aspx), but it seems to work well without a problem.

Comment: This is not working for me (using a Batch with Method Update from the SOAP webservice API).

Comment: I think this is on an SPListItem, a class in Microsoft.SharePoint namespace. You can only use that class on the server itself, not from any webservice.

Comment: In SP2013, trying to use this code to change from "Test.docx" to "Test.pdf" will result in a file called "Test.pdf.docx"